# SaveChanges query generation performance

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

It appears that SaveChanges is very slow when saving lots of records, even if the records are of the same type. The image below shows a profiling session of an attempt to save ~60000 records, the records are of mixed types, however many of them share the same type. My expectaion was that CreateDbCommandDefinition called by SaveChanges will be called once per records type, surprisingly it's being called for each record seperately. This results in bad performance of course.

I checked this both with EF 4.3.1 and 5.0, same results. Is there anyway to configure EF in such a way that it doesn't create a command per each records inserted/updated in the db?

Answer (score 2):

EF executes each modification in separate SQL command and separate roundtrip to database - that is the main reason for a bad performance. There is currently no way to change this unless you download [EF source code](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/) from codeplex and implement command batching yourselves - there is even [related work item](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/53) and [feature request](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015357-batch-cud-support).